# Open Clion from terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, text-editor, clion

I've been trying to set a path to Clion directory in my computer in order to open this program with a command in terminal, but it didn't worked.

If you read this and asked yourself: "what?". I want to start a C++ project like I  did with a normal text editor(I used to write codes with gedit).

I want something like, make a hello world:

```
Clion helloWorld.cpp &
```

And it will open a new project, named helloWorld, and then I can write down the code.

If it is impossible to do that, sorry.

Comment: Please paste what have you tried so far

Comment: I tried to set a sym link, with ln command and I guess that kind of messed up my notebook. I kind of created a /home/userName/userName/(other directories). 

I also tried to add export lines in the end of my ~./profile archive

Comment: "Add "{installation home}/bin" to your PATH environment
     variable so that you may start CLion from any directory."

This is in the installation.txt. But I couldn't do it.

Comment: If you use bash try adding `PATH=$PATH:{installation home}/bin` at the and of your `bash.rc` in your home folder

Comment: I've read something that this is a temporally solution and I should add that in a `~/.profile` file

Comment: **Where** did you install `CLion`, e.g. did you install in `$HOME/CLion` or in `/opt` or somewhere else?

Comment: `/home/gabriel/Documents/clion-2016.3.2` is where my `Clion` is. And I only `./clion.sh` at `/home/gabriel/Documents/clion-2016.3.2/bin` folder in terminal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start **CLion** using the GUI interface, then start Terminal and run the following to find what process is running:

```
ps -ae| grep lion
```

**Output**

```
57257 ??         0:20.45 /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/MacOS/clion
57434 ttys000    0:00.00 grep lion
```

So the command I need to use, in my case, to start CLion from the command line is:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/MacOS/clion
```

Then you need to pass the directory containing your project, so you could make a function like this:

```
function CLion {  /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/MacOS/clion "$1"; }
```

Then you can just type:

```
Clion ~/CLionProjects/someProject
```

Comment: `ps -ae| grep lion`

gives me no Output

but, if I open clion.sh, manually, i get this as Output

`6342 ?        00:00:00 clion.sh`

Comment: Did you start `CLion` via the GUI first? And as the same user? Try `ps -aef | grep -i CLion`

Comment: My output

`gabriel   8186  5484  0 10:59 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./clion.sh`

and

`gabriel   8281  8241  0 10:59 pts/2    00:00:00 /home/gabriel/Documents/clion-2016.3.2/bin/fsnotifier64`

which one I use?

Comment: I think we must have installed `CLion` differently. I used `homebrew` to install mine very simply with `brew install Caskroom/cask/clion` so if you installed from source, your setup may differ. I'll ask some questions in a moment.

Comment: It worked, I used `/home/userName/Documents/clion-2016.3.2/bin/clion.sh`

Comment: Use `locate clion.sh` on Ubuntu

Comment: Why not just put it in an alias instead of a wrapper function?
`alias clion="/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/MacOS/clion"`

Answer (score 11):

In researching this question, I just discovered that there is an officially supported method for doing this is via `CLion`'s `Tools|Create Command Line Launcher...` menu item.

Full details are posted here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html

Answer (score 7):

For Mac users, you need to add following row in ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias clion='open -na "CLion.app" --args "$@"'
```

Then from the terminal you can run CLion:

```
clion /path-to-your-project
```

Comment: For some reason this does not open new app instance...

Comment: It should be noted that with new OS changes you might need to add that line into `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`.
Then, remember to source the file (either `. ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`, or simply closing and reopening/loading the terminal).

Answer (score 1):

If you use JetBrains Toolbox to manage your `CLion` (or other IntelliJ) apps like I do, you'll find that Toolbox installs `CLion` with a versioned pathname.  This means every time you update `CLion`, the path to the `clion.sh` launcher script changes.

For Linux environments, you can use the following in your `~/.bash_profile` to handle this:

```sh
alias clion="`find ~/.local -iname clion.sh | head -1` >/dev/null &" #Linux
```

or

```sh
alias clion='open -n "$(IFS=$'\n' && find "${HOME}/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion" -iname clion.app | head -1)"' #Mac OS X
```

If you upgrade your `CLion` you can restart your terminal or just run `. ~/.bashrc` to update the `clion` alias.